# Slot Machine - Total Hits

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a slot game machine with $5$ reels, a $(3\times 5)$ play window and $1$ payline.
Each reel contains symbols, which in this case are labeled by numbers from $0$ to $8$, where $8$ is the symbol that pays the most.
All reels spin independently of each other.

I have an *Excel* table that stores the symbols that occurred in Reels $1-5$ across some rows.
I've also stored the amount of times the symbol $n$ occurs in reel $p$, namely $n_p$ where $n \in \{0,...,8\}$ and $p \in \{1,...,5\}$ as well as the total amount of times **any** symbol occurs in reel $p$, that is
$$\Sigma_p = 0_p \space + \space ... \space + \space 8_p$$ where $$ p = 1, ..., 5$$

For example, if I wish to calculate the total amount of times the payline hits a prize corresponding to a sequence of size $5$ for the symbol $0$, there's obviously only one possibility, namely $(0,0,0,0,0)$ resulting in

$$0_1 \times 0_2 \times 0_3 \times 0_4 \times 0_5$$ amount of times (the total amount of times the paylines hit a prize corresponding to a sequence of five zeroes).

In the same fashion, if I wish to compute the total hits for a sequence of size $4$ for the symbol $0$, there's two possibilities: $(X,0,0,0,0)$ or $(0,0,0,0,X)$, where $X$ here means any symbol other than $0$.

That is, $ (\Sigma_1 - 0_1) \times 0_2 \times 0_3 \times 0_4 \times 0_5  + 0_1 \times 0_2 \times 0_3 \times 0_4 \times (\Sigma_5 - 0_5)$ amount of times.

A sequence of size $3$ yields $10$ different possibilities that ought to be taken into account.

Is the reasoning correct, though?
I ask this because I computed the total hits for a sequence of size $5$ and it worked as expected, but when I tried for a sequence of size $4$ it did not concur.

Comment: I fixed a typo, but now wonder if it's more than that: you should have $n \in \{1,...,9\}$, not $8$! Seen?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach assuming the 0s have to be next to each other.  It seems likely you have a bug in the code.

Comment: The symbols only run from $0$ to $8$, it's literally part of the conditions of the problem, the number $9$ could be included, it simply is not by the very definition of the problem.
EDIT: sorry, my bad. you're right!

Comment: @lefebvrelea You misunderstand. If symbols run from $0$ to $8$, then there are nine of them in total.

Comment: To clarify, does $\Sigma_p = 0_p+1_p+2_p+\dots+8_p$? If yes, your expression should be correct (and my answer is dead wrong).

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: Explain again what your Sigma means, please. Why would occurences in rows 2+ matter for row 1?

Comment: In other words: when you write "amount of times", do you mean "probability"?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, Sigma was indeed misdefined.
I've already edited the main thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work appears to be correct. The number of ways to get exactly four zeros in a row, meaning that $5$ zeroes in a row is excluded, is
$$
\;\;\;\,(\Sigma_1- 0_1) \times 0_2 \times 0_3 \times 0_4 \times 0_5  \\+ 0_1 \times 0_2 \times 0_3 \times 0_4 \times (\Sigma_5 - 0_5)
$$
I have confirmed this with Python simulation.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPbjtowEH3GXzHVPpCwKUuAbCuk/YZKbV8qNopMcMDaxEa2I8pWfDsd27mtgL6USGDGc@bMmTk5nMxeisXlUihZgaJiiz@8OkhlIN9LnjNCRF1lhmmj4QUWMIF4BpMJJIQoxkob3PLcBKH/u45TjKxnkX1ifObRIlpGSfQcfYm@pk3SvEu6k7BoEuZ41QWXg9JL@7QXyeCi5fXc85SQLStA811Fg7dwRUaKmVoJKJkIPPotDZ3IDVOZLLKD1JpvSpbpAxdWnsfGIUr3x3l/XPTHZX9MfMHsSE86MzI7coF1XknQlfoM7bSmuayFCWahhbfT6YJdbHEjtrwRSwaxR6SE4eeK8z8pg1Zup2dIj0N4gB@8qktquBTNSPxMZ6SQCjLAwaDpdizoTIYrIqMH@O6sWJ6sC6VmQEGfqo0swRmV0XzvGKdkdFD8nWUlF8yawJu22SxPQ7A8vOeJI3gOU0fxS9ZgN8MLMHsGBVfaYHqtGioNVDF4Z0oyHQH249JKillcg5AmAqlsoaaAu/mIZ@oK72lcAWweoUEvYD1bWY/3Xk4dbJCA159weiEy43JHuNMhPF4l/4bPGji@BqNuG48vEBOCWbg2MirGP/cMdVvtf@69FWdo/4P1uBsyLUtvAjASZyG201cxtvW@ufFonxrZc1N6@H6cfSGEasaA/aa5Oflh@gHaDVJQ8thWxS5RmdzQDS855srCIrnYfURpz4cNXnPCE9wViDQDIu1dzLagS2mgQvtZvx2pBn2oha/s7HsGw6t2300Fr/jYy3YTxC9DRY5NYuu3lEYNXEtnnL6HoWwU2NV86ruYjklILpe/)

For $3$ zeroes in a row, the answer is
$$
\;\;\;\,(\Sigma_1-0_1)\times (\Sigma_2-0_2)\times 0_3\times 0_4\times 0_5\\
+(\Sigma_1-0_1)\times 0_2\times 0_3\times 0_4\times (\Sigma_5-0_5)\\
+0_1\times 0_2\times 0_3\times (\Sigma_4-0_4)\times (\Sigma_5-0_5)
$$

Comment: I forgot to consider only $0$ values close to each other, which leaves out only three possible cases when considering $3$ zeroes in a row. Thanks!
I understood the point you made, unfortunately it still doesn't yield the expected results.

Comment: I still think that the amount of times $0$ doesn't land in the first reel is the amount times any other value may land there, and that is $\Sigma_1 - 0_1$. But your approach also doesn't seem wrong, so I'm confused.

Comment: That's okay! Also, the expected total hits for a sequence of size either $1$ or $2$ should be equal to zero, I still don't know why this is the case.

Comment: What makes you think your expression for four-zeroes-in-a-row is wrong? Did you simulate the slot machine? I did some simulations, and the results agreed with your formula. I edited my answer with a link to my Python code. @lefebvrelea

Comment: Thanks for the script, looks neat!
I've gotten the same result using my data running your script, as I would using Excel (no surprise). This is part of an exercise I was meant to do, although unfortunately I'm not allowed to use scripts. I'm starting to second guess the expected solution.